# "В том местечке жил благочестивый человек(,) по имени Азарио". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Согласно правилу, без интонации обособления приложение со словами *по имени, фамилии, по прозвищу* не выделяются запятыми: *Маленький чернявый лейтенант, **по фамилии Жук**, привел батальон к задним дворам той улицы.* Но (без интонации обособления): *Завел он себе медвеженка **по имени Яша**. Мы познакомились с немецким врачом **по фамилии Шульц**.*

- Что такое интонация? Она ведь индивидуальна, и одно и то же предложение два человека читают по-разному: один с интонацией обособления, другой — без нее.
- Читается ли с интонацией обособления это предложение: ***В том местечке жил благочестивый человек(,) по имени Азарио***? Нет ли какого-то более объективного условия для данных случаев? Или все объективно, только мне иначе кажется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обособление зависит от вида предложения:

В том местечке жил благочестивый человек **по имени Азарио.**  В предложении такой структуры  неудобно делать паузу, поэтому слово с неопред. значением ***человек*** имеет два определения.

В том местечке жил **один** благочестивый человек, **по имени Азарио**.  Это уточнение.

Однажды в то местечко пришел благочестивый человек, **по имени Азарио**. Это дополнительная информация, здесь главное то, что он был благочестивый.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А как быть в таких ситуациях? В том селении жил один глубокий старец по имени Симеон (запятая не очень просится). А уже здесь хочется поставить: В том селении жил один старец, по имени Симеон.

Comment: Обособление оборотов со словами  "по имени" факультативное, и здесь действительно решение часто подсказывает структура предложения. (1) В том селении /жил один глубокий стАрец //по имени СимеОн. Предложение удобно разделить на три части: детерминант (он не имеет ударения, отделен небольшой паузой) + простое предложение, разбитое на две фразы с двумя ударениями (запятая не ставится). (2) В том селении жил один стАрец, // по имени СимеОн. Менее распространенное  предложение разбивается на две части, оборот обособляется.

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению (или к счастью), более объективных условий нет, здесь свобода автора в выражении своей мысли.

Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если служит для пояснения или уточнения нарицательного существительного (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова «а зовут его», «а именно», «то есть», например: *Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Тургенев); У дверей, на солнышке, зажмурившись, лежала любимая собака отца – Милка (Л. Толстой); А братья Ани, Петя и Андрюша, гимназисты, дёргали его (отца) сзади за фрак и шептали сконфуженно… (Чехов).*

Во многих случаях возможна двоякая пунктуация, в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия пояснительного оттенка и соответствующей интонации при чтении. Ср.:

а) *Один только казак, Максим Голодуха, вырвался дорогою из татарских рук (Гоголь)*; *Елизавета Алексеевна поехала погостить к брату, Аркадию Алексеевичу* 
 (у нее только один брат; если бы было несколько, то при выражении то же мысли собственное имя не следовало бы обособлять); Он сына моего, Борьку, напомнил (то же основание);

б) *Вошла его сестра Мария; Сегодня я и друг мой Валентин уезжаем в Копенгаген; Распорядился староста курса Дима Шилов; В коридоре показался учитель математики Куликов Сергей Павлович.*

Answer (score 2):

Так пунктуация как раз и нужна для того, чтобы все люди прочитали конкретное предложение с нужной интонацией и правильно поняли смысл. И именно поэтому в идеале нужно согласование с автором текста, если не сам автор расставляет знаки препинания, и в спорных случаях решение остаётся за автором.

На мой взгляд, в Вашем случае обособление не нужно, это не уточнение, просто *человек по имени Азарио*. Хотя, конечно, контекст может повлиять на интонацию и, соответственно, обособление.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша воля ставить или не ставить запятую, но учтите, что текст будет восприниматься (и произноситься) по-разному. Если стоит запятая, то "по имени Азарио" — пояснение, при чтении нужно делать паузу.